# Using GCM for device to device app data sync

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am planning to build a shopping list application, wherein grocery items from one user (tied to one google account on the smartphone) can be sent over to another app user (tied to another google account on his/her smartphone).

Seeing GCM, I am not sure, if we can do a device to device kind of data sync? Any ideas on how this sort of stuff is basically implemented in a quick and easy way would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you dont necessarily need to use GCM or any messaging service, all gcm is meant to do is notify a device that something has changed on your server and that you need to go get all the new stuff.

that being said all you need to do is just have a sync button that the user can manually sync the list from the server to the device and vice versa which would get rid of the need for GCM.

if you wanted automatic syncing then GCM or any other messaging service would be what you want

Comment: But how would the list item data from my device (from within the shopping list app) go over to the server and how would the other device (using my same app but registered with a different google id) get that data without using GCM. I am a slightly newbie to this whole GCM stuff, so pardon me, if I am asking silly questions.

Comment: you use a web service call (HTTP Post or other) sending the data to the server and back. this really has nothing to do with GCM, all GCM is suppose to do is alert your device that you need to call the server because there was an update and nothing more

Comment: I was also looking at using the Google App Engine Plugin for Eclipse as I dont plan to host my own web / web service as a server component. I just simply need a way to be able to let 2 predefined google accounts transfer data to each other (apart from bluetooth as I don't believe my paired app users would always be colocated to use Bluetooth).

Comment: yes google app engine is one of the many options what you should be looking into to store your data

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on tyczj's answer, you will need a server anyway to store GCM registration ids from your users. So you can use the same server to host groceries items for them.

So the flow will be like this:

1. User A wish to send groceries list to User B, he uploads groceries list via your server's Web Service API, along with User B's google email address.
2. Your server has a list of GCM registration ids, which will be associated with their google email address. The server finds the GCM regid of user B, and push a notification with a URL to download the groceries list to him.
3. User B's phone receives GCM message, display a notification to let the user download the groceries list from the URL in the GCM message.

GCM is only needed if you want this 'real-time' way of syncing the list. You could also omit GCM, in which case, User B will only know User A has shared the list with him, when he runs the app (i.e. every time app is run, it will perform 'is there someone sharing a list with me' command).

Comment: Thanks a lot @azgolfer and tyczj for the nice clarity on this topic. That gives me at least some confidence now, to venture into something unseen.